# Font is not loaded beforehand when loading Ajax content into div (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax, wordpress

I'm using a JS function in Wordpress with Ajax that loads content of a post in a modal div when certain elements are clicked. The JS function looks like this:

```
function openProjectModal($that) {

    var post_id = $that.attr("rel");
    window.location.hash = $that.data("slug");
    $("#content-projects").load(localization.ajax_url+"?action=load_more_post&pid="+post_id,{},function(data,status){
        initImageLoad();
    });
    }
```

The function that creates the markup in `functions.php` looks like this:

```
function load_more_post_callback() {
    if( isset($_GET["pid"]) ){
        $post = get_post( $_GET["pid"] );
        if( $post instanceof WP_Post ) {
            echo '<div id="close"></div>';
            echo '<section id="title-projects"><h1>' . get_the_title($post->ID) . '</h1><p class="project-meta">' . get_field("location", $post->ID) . ' (' . get_field("year", $post->ID) . ')</p></section>';
        } else {
            // nothing found with the post id
        }
    } else {
        // no post id
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

The `h1` in the new content has a font applied to it through CSS that isn't used on the initial page. So when the div gets loaded with the content from the Ajax call, there is a delay in the loading of the font, which looks weird. It goes from blank, to Times New Roman, to the right font. When I close the modal and open a new one, the font is instantly loaded like it should be. I guess that it gets cached from the first load.

I've added the fonts in the CSS that is being used on the whole site, but it seems like the browser only loads the fonts that are actually being used in the markup, since this font that is unique for the Ajax content gets loaded when the Ajax content gets loaded.

I've only noticed this in Safari though, but it would be nice if there was a workaround for this even if it's just a special issue in Safari. Any ideas on how to preload the font before it's shown?

Comment: _“Any ideas on how to preload the font before it's shown?”_ - either _put_ an element that uses this font somewhere on the page to begin with … or type “font loader” into Google.

Comment: Well, I really don't want the design to be affected in order to work around this issue. I could set it to something that's hidden, but that would just feel like a hack. But I'll read about font loader.

Answer (score 0):

In your modal simply do

```
<h2 class="myTitleFont">Title</h2>
```

Then in `css` you can do:

```
.myTitleFont {
   font-family. "yourFont";
}
```

or if really you have to:

```
.myTitleFont {
   font-family: "yourFont" !important;
}
```

Obviously "*yourFont*" is the name of your `font`.

Comment: Is this different from applying the font to the `h2` itself? Does classes work differently?

There's also a typo I think in the `important!` section. it should be `font-family: "your font"!important;`. And colons instead of dots after the properties. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: ok for the dot, yeah was a typo. !important can be right next to it or with a space in between. And in regards of your question, it depends, I don't know if you have already given a font-family to h2 globally on your site, by providing a custom class to your specific h2 which calls a custom font-family should work. Have you tried?

Comment: Yeah, I was more pointing out that the `!important` statement is within the quotation marks in your code. :)
And yes, I've already applied the font to the `h1` tag itself, so I don't think it would behave differently if the font was applied to a class. At least if neither the `h1` nor the class is present on the initial page. But I could of course try it just in case.

Comment: the fact you are calling content via ajax, doesn't effect the style since the font called from remote would have being already loaded into the page itself and registered with the browser behaviour

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking too, that it would already be loaded since it's declared in the CSS. But at least in Safari, there's a clear delay when opening the modal for this specific font. I actually tried applying the font to a random element on the initial page, and that fixed the delay. But I feel like there should be some way to work around this other than being forced to apply the font to something on the initial page. So maybe font loader is the way to go, like mentioned in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

I still believe is just a css issue, however, create a callback for your modal when it is opened and run:

```
$(".modal").on.("show", function(){
   addGoogleFont();
});

function addGoogleFont() {
    $("head").append("<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=" + FontName + "' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");
    $(".modal h2").css("opacity", "1");
}
```

And set your modal h2 to opacity 0 so you won't see it until

```
.modal h2 {
   opacity: 0;
}
```